# How to make sorting?

Tags: node.js, knex.js

If  look at the example in the documentation knex then sorting is done this way:

```
.orderBy('name', 'desc')
```

How to sort, if want the name to be sorted both in ascending order and in descending order, depending on what values ​​were specified in the route `?order=asc` or `?order=desc`.

I tried to do so `.orderBy('name', req.orderBy)`, but it does not  help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.orderBy('name', req.query.order)
```

Try like this